# Webpack final bundle size is too big

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

Making build using webpack 4.9.1 using `npm run build`

Package.json file command

`"build": "webpack --mode production --config webpack.config.prod.js",`

After build my bundle size is 1010 KiB which is too huge. trying to figure out since day but no success so finally putting here

[image]

webpack.config.prod.js

```js
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  devtool: 'none',
  entry: {
    index: './src/index.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({ options: {} }),
    new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin(),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: 'style.css',
      },
      {
        from: 'bootstrap.min.css',
      },
      {
        from: 'index.html',
      }
    ]),
    new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
  ],
  module: {
    noParse:[ /node_modules\/localforage\/dist\/localforage.js/],
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        enforce: "pre",
        loaders: ['eslint-loader'],
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loaders: ['babel-loader'],
        include: [path.join(__dirname, 'src'), path.join(__dirname, 'translations')]
      },
      {
        // do not exclude node_modules, since map.json is in node_modules
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loaders: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
      },
    ]
  }
};
```

my .babelrc looks like below

```js
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-2"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": [
        ["react-transform", {
          "transforms": [{
            "transform": "react-transform-hmr",
            "imports": ["react"],
            "locals": ["module"],
            "preventFullImport": true
          }, {
            "transform": "react-transform-catch-errors",
            "imports": ["react", "redbox-react"],
            "preventFullImport": true
          }]
        }]
      ]
    }
  },
  "plugins": [
    ["transform-object-rest-spread"],
    ["transform-react-display-name"],
    ["module-resolver", {
      "root": ["./src"]
    }]
  ]
}
```

I know I am missing something here.

Should be somewhere near to or more than webpack recommendations but 1010 KB is too much

FROM BUILD LOGS

WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
Entrypoints:
  index (1010 KiB)
      bundle.js

**Other relevant information:**

1. webpack version:  webpack 4.9.1
2. Node.js version: v6.10.0 Operating
3. System: mac OS Additional
4. tools: npm -v = 4.1.2

Answer (score 4):

You might want to consider splitting your chunks. Like you can have separate chunk for your own code and `node_modules`.

You might want to minify your code in production mode to reduce the bundle size.
Here's what you can do with your webpack config file:

```
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

optimization: splitChunks: {
    cacheGroups: {
      vendor: {
        chunks: "initial",
        test: path.resolve(process.cwd(), "node_modules"),
        name: "vendor",
        enforce: true
      }
    }
  },
  minimizer: [
    new UglifyJSPlugin({
      uglifyOptions: {
        sourceMap: true,
        compress: {
          drop_console: true,
          conditionals: true,
          unused: true,
          comparisons: true,
          dead_code: true,
          if_return: true,
          join_vars: true,
          warnings: false
        },
        output: {
          comments: false
        }
      }
    })
  ]
```

This will create separate bundle for your `node_module` which you can include in your main file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, did that not much improvement.
My app is very small, now I have started to think alternatives of webpack

Comment: @PradeepJaiswar adds lazy load to your component. You can also remove this warning.